# Threading in Android

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I have just started Android Development, I want to make thread in my application which get the current location after every thirty seconds. Kindly give me some hints or any tutorial link which you think is useful for this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you need to create handler and update the gui every thirty seconds using that handler. For more info how to update the gui click [here](http://me.codingthings.com/blog/android-sdk-timers-and-gui-update/). For more info how the get the location read this [android get location from best provider available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2919358/android-get-location-from-best-provider-available)

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html) is a good place to start. Note that if you are new to Android development you will find a lot of good resources at the Android [website](http://developer.android.com/index.html). Start there and maybe grab a good book on threads in Java, [this one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321349601) is very good book for that.