# LocationManager's getBestProvider returning null

Tags: android, android-location

I have a bunch of people reporting an error that I cannot reproduce. When trying to open a `MapView` it's reporting that the `getBestProvider` is returning null and I know that means that that no provider is found that fulfills my criteria which is `ACCURACY_COARSE` so if there is no GPS then it should fall back on either `network or passive` but it obviously doesn't on those user devices. What would that even mean then that GPS is off and there is no network connection?

I tried turning GPS off and putting the phone into airplane mode to try to reproduce the problem but still I was able to open the mapview without a force close so I don't know how to handle this problem.

```java
locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
geocoder = new Geocoder(this);

Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_COARSE);
List<String> lProviders = locationManager.getProviders(false);
for(int i=0; i<lProviders.size(); i++){
    Log.d("LocationActivity", lProviders.get(i));
}
String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true); // null

long minTime = 60000;
float minDistance = 5;

locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, minTime, minDistance, this);
```

error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ecm2.android/ecm2.android.LocationActivity}: 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: provider==null
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: provider==null
at android.location.LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.java:625)
at ecm2.android.LocationActivity.onCreate(LocationActivity.java:142)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In your call to `getBestProvider()` you've asked for **enabled providers only** (that's the second parameter in the method call which you have set to `true`). If the user has disabled all providers, you will get `null`.

In any case, you need to be able to deal with the situation where there are no available providers, so you'll need to check for `null` and tell the user that he has not enabled any location.

Comment: right I understand that but even when I disable GPS and turn the phone into airplane mode which would mean it does not have network access either I still dont get that problem so how are they? what else can be disabled?

Comment: You can disable **location**, which means that the user doesn't allow the application to get his location by any means. Also, this is going to be a vendor-specific thing. I was able to get `null` on my HTC Explorer. It may be different with different devices.

Comment: add these to the manifest

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>

Answer (score 6):

**androidManifest.xml**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
```

**MapsActivity.java**

```
 @Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    if (permissions.length == 1 &&
            permissions[0] == android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION &&
            grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    } else {
        // Permission was denied. Display an error message.
    }
}
```

**MapsActivity.java/onCreate()**

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    } else {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1);
    }
```

this work for me;