# Location provider=null, android

Tags: android

I am writing android application to get latitude and longitude. I did this in a aysnctask, but it says that the provider is null. this is the code:

```
private class GetCurrentAddress extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String[]> {
    @Override
    protected String[] doInBackground(String... urls) {

         locationManager=(LocationManager) getSystemService(context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
         criteria=new Criteria();
        String provider=locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
        Location loc=locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
        String[] a = null;
        //double 
        lat=loc.getLatitude();
        //double 
        lng=loc.getLongitude();
         currentLatitude = Double.toString(lat);
         currentLongitude = Double.toString(lng);
         a[0]=currentLatitude;
         a[1]=currentLongitude;
        return a;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String[] resultString) {
        dialog.dismiss();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "latt="+resultString[0], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "langg="+resultString[1], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

here is the LogCat:

```
12-03 22:13:35.184: E/AndroidRuntime(10016): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
12-03 22:13:35.184: E/AndroidRuntime(10016): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
12-03 22:13:35.184: E/AndroidRuntime(10016):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
12-03 22:13:35.184: E/AndroidRuntime(10016):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
12-03 22:13:35.184: E/AndroidRuntime(10016):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
12-03 22:13:35.184: E/AndroidRuntime(10016):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
12-03 22:13:35.184: E/AndroidRuntime(10016):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
12-03 22:13:35.184: E/AndroidRuntime(10016):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
12-03 22:13:35.184: E/AndroidRuntime(10016):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
12-03 22:13:35.184: E/AndroidRuntime(10016):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
12-03 22:13:35.184: E/AndroidRuntime(10016):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
12-03 22:13:35.184: E/AndroidRuntime(10016): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: provider==null
12-03 22:13:35.184: E/AndroidRuntime(10016):    at android.location.LocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.java:1159)
12-03 22:13:35.184: E/AndroidRuntime(10016):    at com.example.weather_our.MainActivity$GetCurrentAddress.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:132)
12-03 22:13:35.184: E/AndroidRuntime(10016):    at com.example.weather_our.MainActivity$GetCurrentAddress.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
12-03 22:13:35.184: E/AndroidRuntime(10016):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
12-03 22:13:35.184: E/AndroidRuntime(10016):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
```

line 132 in MainActivity is :
Location loc=locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

Comment: possible duplicate of [LocationManager's getBestProvider returning null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10687409/locationmanagers-getbestprovider-returning-null)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check to be sure you have the proper permission requested in your manifest.

From the API documentation:

> Unless noted, all Location API methods require the
>   ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION or ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permissions. If your
>   application only has the coarse permission then it will not have
>   access to the GPS or passive location providers. Other providers will
>   still return location results, but the update rate will be throttled
>   and the exact location will be obfuscated to a coarse level of
>   accuracy.