# locationManager.getBestProvider return null

Tags: android, location, maps, parse-server

I have a problem with provider apparently, my app crashes on launch although i enabled COARSE and FINE location permissions in my manifest. I have also INTERNET permission added.

My code :

```
locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(new Criteria(), false);

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                this,
                new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                PERMISSION_LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE);
    }
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 400, 1, this);
```

And here is the logcat:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.project.korsa.korsa, PID: 32462
              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.project.korsa.korsa/com.project.korsa.korsa.YourLocation}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid provider: null
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3305)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3401)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:229)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1821)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7303)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
               Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid provider: null
                  at android.location.LocationManager.checkProvider(LocationManager.java:1761)
                  at android.location.LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.java:464)
                  at com.project.korsa.korsa.YourLocation.onCreate(YourLocation.java:135)
                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6904)
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1136)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3252)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3401) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:229) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1821) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7303) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Comment: Are you sure you explicitly request the location permissions ? Just declaring it in manifest xml won't work as these are dangerous permissions, they need to be taken explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

check this anwser
https://stackoverflow.com/a/10688606/3973521

> In your call to getBestProvider() you've asked for enabled providers
>   only (that's the second parameter in the method call which you have
>   set to true). If the user has disabled all providers, you will get
>   null.